# update, обновить записи в БД массивом

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Доброго времени суток, который обновляет строку в БД, а нужно 3, 
есть массив $arr, такого вида:

```
Array ( [0] => USD: 26.10000
[1] => EUR: 32.20000
[2] => RUR: 0.45000
)
```

'USD','EUR','RUR' соответствуют полю **title** в БД, цифровые значения полю **value**

```
  function update_kurs($course_curr){
      global $connection;
           $arr2 = ['USD','EUR','RUR'];
       $query = "UPDATE kurs SET value = '$course_curr' WHERE title='$arr2'";
   $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
   if(mysqli_affected_rows($connection)) return true;
   else return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, массив Вы получаете с Вашего предыдущего вопроса)
Если использовать массив вида:

```
$course_curr = [
    'USD: 26.10000',
    'EUR: 32.20000',
    'RUR: 0.45000'
];
```

Код для запроса может быть таким:

```
function update_kurs($course_curr){
    global $connection;
    foreach($course_curr as $curr){
        $curr = explode(':',$curr);
        $query = "UPDATE kurs SET value = '".trim($curr[1])."' WHERE title='".trim($curr[0])."'";
        $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($connection)) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Все таки, я бы формировал массив такого вида:

```
$course_curr = [
    'USD' => '26.10000',
    'EUR' => '32.20000',
    'RUR' => '0.45000'
];
```

С таким массивом проще работать.
Тогда код запроса был бы немного проще:

```
function update_kurs($course_curr){
    global $connection;
    foreach($course_curr as $key=>$curr){
        $query = "UPDATE kurs SET value='$curr' WHERE title='$key'";
        $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($connection)) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Разберитесь сначала в коде, почитайте по нему документацию, а потом уже задавайте вопрос.

[explode php](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)

[UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

Comment: массив $course_curr такого вида Array ( [0] => USD: 26.10000 [1] => EUR: 32.20000 [2] => RUR: 0.45000 )

Comment: по второму примеру, ничего не обновляется в БД

Comment: Вы ответ прочитали, или просто скопировали код? Для массива вида Array ( [0] => USD: 26.10000 [1] => EUR: 32.20000 [2] => RUR: 0.45000 ) первый пример кода!

Comment: все сделал по второму варианту, нужно было массив преобразовать как было сказано

Answer (score 0):

Возможно целесообразнее пользоваться `serialize()` и хранить значения в одной ячейке т.е. в базу записывайте `serialize($ваш_массив)`, а когда получаете данные с бд делаете `unserialize($результат)`

Comment: использую $array_data = serialize($course_curr); и в БД ничего не происходит, просто не записывает